# Angularjs evauate when data it ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am developing my first angular-app with an .Net backend.

I get my data async from a webmethod using a http.post. That all works fine.
Client-side I would like to do some simple calculations (a final row in a table which contains sums of all the data in table)

The code to do this is pretty straight forward but my problem is the data i not ready when I try to do it.

I have read that I could use a promise and a service or a factory. But I am not sure what we be the best way to go.

My code for the view:

```
<div ng-controller="taskCtrl as ctrl"> 
<div class="col-md-10 container outer">
<h1 class="center-block">{{ctrl.SprintViewModel.SprintName}}</h1>
    <table id="SprintMetaDate">
        <tr><td>Projekt:</td><td>{{ctrl.SprintViewModel.ProjektName}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Periode:</td><td>{{ctrl.SprintViewModel.StartDate}} - {{Ctrl.SprintViewModel.EndDate}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Udarbejdet af/d:</td><td>{{ctrl.SprintViewModel.MadeBy}}</td></tr>
    </table>

    <h3>Sprint Resume:</h3>
    <br/>
    {{ctrl.SprintViewModel.SprintResume}}
    <h3>Sprint afslutning:</h3>
    {{ctrl.SprintViewModel.SprintDemo}}

    <h2>Scope og Økonomi </h2> 
    <h3>Sprint Opgaver</h3> 


    <table id="SprintTasks" class="col-md-12">
        <tr><th>Opgave</th><th>Estimat</th><th>Forbrug</th><th>Udest.</th><th>*</th><th>Pris (DKK)</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in ctrl.SprintViewModel.Tasks">
            <td style="width: 40%">{{ x.Description }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.TimeEst }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.TimeUsed }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.TimeRemaining }}</td>
            <td>{{ ctrl.CalcPrecisionOfEstimat(x.TimeUsed,x.TimeRemaining,x.TimeEst) | number:2}} %</td>
            <td>{{x.Price}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ialt</td>
            <td>{{ ctrl.TotalEstimat() }}</td>
            <td>{{ ctrl.TotalTimeUsed() }}</td>
            <td>{{ctrl.TotalTimeRemaining()}}</td>
            <td>{{ctrl.TotalPrecision()}}</td>
            <td>{{ctrl.TotalPrice()}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        * Forbrug + Udestående i forhold til estimat

    <br/>

    Udestående opgaver er planlagt ind i næstkommende sprint.
    </div>


</div>
</form>
 <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('taskCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.SprintViewModel = null;


        ctrl.TotalEstimat=function() {
            var totalEstimat=0;
           for (i=0; i<ctrl.SprintViewModel.Tasks.count;i++) {
                totalEstimat += ctrl.SprintViewModel.Tasks[i].Estimate;
            }
            return totalEstimat;
        }


        ctrl.TotalPrecision = function () {
            var totalPrecision=0;
            angular.forEach(ctrl.SprintViewModel.Tasks, function (value, key) {
                totalPrecision += Number(value);


            });

        $http.post('SprintRapport.aspx/GetSprintViewModel', {})
            .then(function(response, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("I success");
                ctrl.SprintViewModel = response.data.d;                  
            });           
    });`
```

As already mentioned I get a nullreference every when the page-load on all the methods in the last row, because ctrl.SprintviewModel is undefined. I have only included one of the methods for simplicity, the problem is the same for all of them.

So my question is how do I make sure that ctrl.TotalEstimat() first get called then ctrl.SprintViewModel is assigned?

Comment: you could add a simple `ng-if="..."` to your `table` element (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ng-if` condition to the last `<tr>` which resolves to true when data is ready to populate in your controller. So you can define `$scope.loading = false` initially and once your code is ready to populate you set `$scope.loading=true` and that will call $digest cycle internally and your view gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you could do. I've fixed this kind of issue by placing guard conditions in the functions. These check that the necessary variables have been set before continuing. So adding `if (!ctrl.SprintViewModel) return;` at the beginning of the function as follows:

```
   ctrl.TotalEstimat=function() {
        // Guard Condition to prevent function executing in invalid state. 
        if (!ctrl.SprintViewModel) return;

        var totalEstimat=0;
       for (i=0; i<ctrl.SprintViewModel.Tasks.count;i++) {
            totalEstimat += ctrl.SprintViewModel.Tasks[i].Estimate;
        }
        return totalEstimat;
    }
```

It's another option, but as you have already alluded to, I think that promises and the `$q` library is the *proper* angular way to fix this sort of thing.